# Unwanted behavior from WebComponents built @angular/elements inside an angular app

Tags: angular, angular-elements

So for my personal project, I am building a WebComponent library built with @angular/elements following this article:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-angular-6-custom-elements-web-components-c88814dc6e0a

Everything is working smoothly in an non-angular context (basic index.html, who load my compiled *file.js* rendering my webcomponents)

However, whenever I load this same file and use those same webcomponents within an angular app, they start behaving weirdly, see example below.

Minimal library exemple from stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdx2vf

Inside an angular app I call my webcomponents by using this code: `<lm-button>Hello</lm-button>`

The rendering is as follow:
[image]

The rendered source code:
[image]

This is the correct rendered source code when I test it outside an angular app context:
[image]

So my question, what am I doing wrong in my library and/or my angular app?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the console